# Function to bring multidimensional array to single dimension?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I suffer for three hours already, trying to bring array from something like this:

```
var mltDim = [/1/, /2/, [/31/, [/321/, /322/, /323/], /33/], /4/, [/51/, /52/], /6/];
```

into this:

```
var oneDim = [/1/, /2/, /31/, /321/, /322/, /323/, /33/, /4/, /51/, /52/, /6/];
```

The additional problem is to make recursive function, because depth of array will not be defined.
All non-Array values will definitely be RegExps, so you may count on it. Non-RegExp values will be filtered out.

---

*P.S.:* Solving this problem, I wrote own `typeOf()` function:

```
var typeOf = obj => obj? obj.constructor.toString().match(/.{9}(\w+)(?=\()/)[1] : "Undefined";
```

I'll use it for defining type of given objects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15030117/1675492

Comment: @IngoBürk: I didn't thing about word `merge`

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky it is an mutidimensional Array of RegExps, I think that JSON methods do not work with this type of object.

Comment: I can't answer your comment because it has been closed but follow this link, I think that it will help you with your task. https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/kw7j05ev/1/

Comment: @elchininet: Of course. I've mentioned it in my post (follow the link). Thank you for help, the problem is already solved :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not follow the link. I'am glad that you have solved your problem ;)